# ruby on rails on ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

I just got ubuntu installed recently and I'm trying to get ruby on rails up and running. I'm working through this tutorial - http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-o...c-introduction

When I run $ rails -v or $ rails new first_app I get the following error...

The program 'rails' can be found in the following packages:
*rails
*ruby-railties-3.2
Try: sudo apt-get install

Being new to both ubuntu and rails, I'm not sure what to do here. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: here is a guide for you to [install rails](http://installfest.railsbridge.org/installfest/ubuntu)

Comment: I've tried to go through this tutorial.  When I get to step 5 and type in gem install rails I get an error.  Unfortunately there's not enough room to paste the error message here so here's a link to an uploaded text file with the error - http://www.textswell.com/read,4233304156962 Any idea what's wrong and how to fix it?  Thanks.

Comment: I "think" I found the problem.  I deleted my .gemrc file and then it appeared to install rails.  Thanks.

Comment: @geoffswartz if you found your own answer it would be good to put is as an answer (yes you can answer your own questions)

Answer (score 0):

Best way to install ruby, rails etc is through RVM. Follow the following links. They'll guide you through.

http://www.unfoldingcode.com/2011/05/using-rvm-to-install-rails-31-on-ubuntu.html
http://siliconchaos.com/2011/07/installing-rails-with-rvm/

Answer (score 0):

Following are the steps to setup `Ruby on rails` on Ubuntu:

1. you need to import the RVM GPG Key:

`gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3`

2. Then install RVM

`curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable`

3. load the RVM script

`source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm`

Following are the steps to create new rails app:

```
1. rails new demo 
2. cd demo
3. rake db:create
4. rails server
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this link. Explained all three ways to install Ruby ( RVM, rbenv and through source) and to setup rails for latest versions of ubuntu separately including DB setup ( MySQL and Postgres).

https://gorails.com/setup/ubuntu/17.04

Comment: While this link may answer the question, link only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow, you can improve this answer by taking vital parts of the link and putting it into your answer, this makes sure your answer is still an answer if the link gets changed or removed :)